# rails syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')' -- moving method from controller to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I moved this method from my controller to my model and am getting the error below.

syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')' @favorite[:phone_number] = reminder[:phone_number] ^

The error only began to appear once I moved it from controller to model. Do note that I did change minor things when i moved it such as giving the method a parameter. Can anyone spot the error?

```
 def self.create_favorite1(reminder_id)
    reminder = Reminder.find (reminder_id)
    if reminder[:favorite] == true

      @favorite = Favorite.create(params.fetch(fav_params)
      @favorite[:phone_number] = reminder[:phone_number]
      @favorite[:picture] = reminder[:picture]
      @favorite[:user_id] = current_user.id
      @favorite.save
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're missing a right paren at the end of this line...

`@favorite = Favorite.create(params.fetch(fav_params)`

Comment: Thanks, that did clear up the error. However, another error appeared. The new error is 'undefined local variable or method `fav_params''. I do have a method in the model 'fav_params'. Any thoughts?